# Does the equation $k^k+1=a^2$ have any positive integer solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

As the title of the question says, I want to know if the equation
$k^k+1=a^2$
has any integer positive solutions, (which means k and a are both positive integers.)
I'd really appreciate it if someone could provide the following:

1. If the given solutions exists, please provide the minimal solution. Are the solutions infinite or finite?
2. If the given solutions doesn't exist, please provide your proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no positive integer solutions by [Mihailescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).

With a less powerful hammer, Ke Zhao proved the nonexistence of solutions to $x^y+1=a^2$ in 1964. See the last reference in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2505858/357390).

Comment: I did not know that the proof of Catalan's conjecture was so recent. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Actually, a less powerful proof suffices for this question. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for this one too ! Cheers :-)

Comment: $$k^k +1=a^2\implies a^2-k^k=1 \implies a = 0 \land k = -1$$

Comment: To whomever is confused by the comment above; the last step makes no sense.

Answer (score 2):

$k^k+1=a^2\Rightarrow k^k=(a-1)(a+1)$

$\gcd(a-1,a+1)=1\text{ or }2$

Case 1: $\gcd(a-1,a+1)=2$. Then $k$ is even, and $k^k$ is a perfect square. The only two squares that differ by $1$ are $0,1$, but $0$ is not a positive integer.

Case 2: $\gcd(a-1,a+1)=1$. Then both $(a-1)$ and $(a+1)$ are perfect $k$th powers that differ by $2$. This can only occur when $k=1$, but $1^1+1=2$ which is not a perfect square.

Comment: This. It's often fun to nuke a mosquito, but when a short and simple argument is available, it should not be left out. With regard to case 1, not only is $0$ ruled out by the positivity requirement, additionally we have $0^0 + 1 = 2$ which is not a square.

Answer (score 0):

$k^k+1$ itself has factors, one of which is $k+1$.  These would have to be coprime, or a common divisor of 2, because the common factor between $(a^k+1)$ and $(k+1)$ would divide 2k.